# Getting confused on return type

Tags: c#, io

Hello I am trying to create a button in C# that if you press it. It should produce a message box on what the IP address is from the attached txt file. But I am getting errors that I not able to fix. I think I have my return type mixed up and I have always had trouble with that here is the code.

```
private String getIPAddress()
    {

        String x;

        using (TextReader configfile = File.OpenText("PC104Configs.txt"))
            while (configfile.Peek() > -1)  // If therre are no more characters in this line
            {
                x = configfile.ReadLine();

                if (x.Length == 0)
                {
                    // This is a blank line
                    continue;
                }

                if (x.Substring(0, 1) == ";")
                {
                    // This is a comment line
                    continue;
                }

                if (x == trueIP)
                {
                    // This is the real deal
                    testPort = configfile.ReadLine();
                    testIP = trueIP;
                    return MessageBox.Show(trueIP);
                }
            }  // End of 'while' there are more characters loop

        UnitToTest.Text = "";

        MessageBox.Show("Specified Configuration Not Found!");

        return (false);
    }


    private void btnSendConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getIPAddress();
    }
```

Comment: "But I am getting errors that I not able to fix." Can you show the error messages?

Comment: Welcome to [so], we've been expecting you. Why do you need to `configfile.ReadLine();` twice and where is trueIP declared?

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, your "getIPAddress" function is supposed to return a string. However, you have it returning a boolean (false). I think you really need to return 'X'. Also, I doubt you really want to return the result from MessageBox.Show(trueIP).

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a boolean from a function expecting to return a string. Therefore, this:

```
private String
```

..is not allowed to return, this:

```
return (false);
```

..or

```
return MessageBox.Show(trueIP);
```

..false is boolean and the Show() method returns a DialogResult, your function must return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `getIPAddress` to return a `String`, but then you subsequently try to return a `DialogResult` and a `bool`.

It sounds like you need to define more precisely what `getIPAddress` should be doing. The function signature implies that you would return a string (or set of strings) containing one or more IP addresses, but what your code seems to want to do is to pop up a message box with the first IP address found.